# Wait in Flutter Code for Completion of Async Native Request

Tags: android, flutter

I am working on a Flutter app, which needs to call an API function `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` in Native code (Android/Java) from Flutter. The API native code function is asynchronous i.e. the call to `requestPermissions` returns immediately and the result of the requestPermissions call is returned later by Android.

How can I wait in Flutter, that when I call the API `requestPermissions` from Flutter via methodChannel, the native code does not return to Flutter immediately, instead wait for the ActivityResult and return the final result to Flutter from Native code. Something like in Flutter

```
int activityResult = await callNativeRequestPermission();
//Now activityResult variable contains the final result
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to request permissions is to use a package such as [permission handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler).

```
onPressed: () async {
  if (await Permission.contacts.request() == PermissionStatus.granted) {
    ...
  }
},
```

It depends on where you are trying to call this from; if it's from a button press it should be easy as you can declare your function as `async` and then use the `await` keyword. If it's when you first open a screen that's a bit more complicated; in that case you could use a FutureBuilder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have checked out the the plugin you mentioned. The reason I didnt go that route was that you need to include all the permissions in your plist file for iOS, even when your application do not need it. There seem to be some hack to fix it, but many users were reporting Apple still rejected their app during review. That's the reason planning to do the permission logic within the app, without the plugin :(.